# Calculate the probability, provided the pdf and cdf

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables

I'm doing the second task of this question:
[image]

I found the probability function like this:

$\quad x\quad -2\quad -0.5\quad 0.5\qquad 1\\p(x)\quad\; 0.3\quad\ 0.2\qquad\ 0.3\quad 0.2$

I also found $P(-1<X<1)=F(1)-F(-1)-P(X=1)=1-0.3-0.2=0.5$

I tried to solve the $P(-1\le X\le1)$ like this: $F(1)-F(-1)+P(X=1)$, but I can't figure out the value of $P(X=1)$

Comment: Please do not post images of text, instead of the text itself. MathJax and table formatting are available. Using images instead of them makes the post less accessible.

Comment: First, you found the probability function, listing $P(X=1)$. Second, shouldn't one of those that you attempted adjust for $P(X=-1)$?

Comment: @AaronGoldsmith I meant $P(X = -1)$, sorry for confusion.

Comment: $P(X=-1)=P(X\le -1)-P(X<-1) = P(X\le -1)-\lim\limits_{x \to -1^{-}}P(X \le x)$, though you have already found the probability mass function for $X$ and there is none at $-1$